# EU Demand For Backdated GDP Bill

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

In 2014 the EU demanded an extra £1.7bn from the UK in a backdated GDP bill because prostitution and illegal drugs were seen as contributing to the British economy.  This would add about a fifth to the UK's annual net contribution of £8.6bn.  Has this bill been paid or is it going to be paid?

Comment: Do you have a source?

Answer (score 2):

This question was (in part) asked during PMQs today, 8 June 2016:

> Karl MᶜCartney (Lincoln) (Con)
>
> Q10. The European Union recently admitted that it now has a black hole
>   in its finances of €24.7 billion—about £19 billion. Eighteen months
>   ago my right hon. Friend declared that he would not pay the EU a £1.7
>   billion surcharge—effectively a fine on British taxpayers for growing
>   our economy—yet he was later forced to pay up. What reassurance can he
>   give the House that hard-working British taxpayers will not be forced
>   to pour money into that EU black hole if our nation votes to remain in
>   the European Union? Does he, like me, accept that our only option to
>   halt such payments is for our constituents to vote to leave the EU on
>   23 June? [905142]
>
> The Prime Minister:
>
> The reassurance that I can give my hon. Friend is that we fixed the
>   European budget for a seven-year period between 2014 and 2020, and we
>   fixed a total for that budget that was lower than for the previous
>   seven-year period, which means that European budgets are going to go
>   down, not up. That cannot be changed. This is a very important point.
>   That overall ceiling of spending is determined by all 28 Prime
>   Ministers and Presidents. There is a veto over changing it, just as
>   there is a veto over the British rebate. The only person who can give
>   up the British rebate is the British Prime Minister, and as long as I
>   am Prime Minister there is absolutely no prospect of that happening.
>   As my hon. Friend ended his question with a remark, I will end my
>   answer with a remark: there is no expert saying that we would make a
>   saving from leaving the EU. The only black hole would be in our public
>   finances, because we would have a smaller economy and lower tax
>   receipts, so we would either have to cut spending or put up taxes to
>   make up for that fact.
>   [Source](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2016-06-08/debates/Hocdebdt20160608scrlgtghs_8Questionod12tiengagements/Engagements)

Later, a fact-checking site commented:

> Mr Cameron is correct on the existence of these two vetoes: one on the
>   overall size of the EU budget, and the other on the UK’s budget rebate
>   (discount).
>
> The amount that the EU is allowed to spend over seven years is set by
>   a unanimous vote of member countries. Budgets for any one year within
>   the seven-year cycle have to stay within these limits.
>
> Although the limits are due to be reviewed by the end of 2016, when a
>   proposal for changing them can be tabled, this too would have to be
>   agreed by all countries.
>
> No country can be forced to find more money to finance unpaid spending
>   commitments from the previous seven-year cycle; that will have to come
>   from the 2014-2020 pot.
>
> The UK has benefitted from a rebate on its EU budget payments since
>   1984. This discount can’t be changed in future without the UK’s agreement.
>
> That’s because the rebate is contained in an EU law that has to be
>   passed by all member countries, which again gives the UK a veto over
>   it.
>
> Other countries may push for the UK to give up some or all of the
>   rebate in exchange for other favours. This happened in 2005, for
>   example. [Source](https://fullfact.org/europe/minimum-wage-workers-rights-and-eu-prime-ministers-questions-factchecked/)